# Which guns are the light machine guns this assignment is talking about?

Tags: battlefield-3

**Which are the "Light Machine Guns" they are referring to here?**

[image]

[Here](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/soldier/capdragon/weapons/199691398/pc/) and [Here](http://denkirson.xanga.com/756891604/bf3/) are possibilities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any gun in the *Support* class counts as an LMG:

- M249
- PKP
- M240B
- M60E4
- M27 IAR
- RPK-74M
- TYPE-88

**Note** This does not include guns that the support can use, only guns that are exclusive to the support class. So any multi class gun is not a LMG. Just because support can use it doesn't make it an LMG. Some guns that *don't* count:

- PDW-4
- UMP-45

Looks to me by your battle-log that you only have the M249, so spawn Support with that and rack up those kills!

Comment: I have the TYPE-88 Too, i guess i'll use that one.

Comment: To be honest I have them all, and I still use the M249. Thing is so accurate and the rate of fire is amazing.